PWM driver for ESP01 using IRFZ44N
Description
I am making a basic led dimmer for a hobby project. I am using ESP01 because its compact and only 1 GPIO is required for this project.
I have a extra IRFZ44N's around so didn't wanna but separate MOS for the project (I know this is probably and overkill for the project and not suitable as ESP have logic voltage of 3.3v). The LED strip I am operating is around 2 Amps with PWM of 1Khz from ESP01.
Issue
The problem I am facing is that sometimes in the low PWM range like 10-30% duty cycle, the circuit I have used seems unstable and flickers. Also I have notices the BJT get's warm (not hot but warm), this could be common but just saying.
Question
How can I improve this circuit, or is there some alternative circuit. I don't want to use push-pull circuit because I have had success with it with the pull-up I am using for ESP01 GPIO2.
Here's the schematic I have used:


what's the purpose of C1?

@RohatKılıç, It wasn't a part of the initial design .. but I saw this get used a lot in push-pull type circuit designs to improve the BJT's turning off response time by providing a negative base current. Not sure if it's required here, but i have experimented with it removed as well .. not sure if there is any visible difference
EDIT:

EDIT:
After your comment I actually tested with this cap removed and present, To my eyes the brightness transitions on LED Strip look smoother with C1 present.

Couple of issues I have noticed:

The effective drive (gate-to-source) voltage when the PWM is low is 6V because of the R2-R3 divider. The lowest on-resistance could be achieved with higher drive voltage. 6V may not be high enough to fully turn on the MOSFET for your application.
If you take the Thevenin equivalent of the 12V source and R2-R3 dividers you'll see that the circuit reduces to a 6V source and a ~5k series resistance (neglecting R4 as it's too low). With the input (gate-source) capacitance of the MOSFET (about 1.5 nF), this effective resistance forms an RC low-pass filter with a cut-off frequency of ~21 kHz. So the sharp edges of the drive signal will be chopped off therefore the duration of the ohmic region operation will increase. This will make the life difficult to drive the MOSFET effectively, therefore increase the losses.

There are also logic-level MOSFETs – they can be driven directly from logic devices such as MCUs. If you can't use another MOSFET at the moment, you can modify your existing circuit into something like following:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The extra Q2-Q3 pair is a totem pole buffer. It has high enough input resistance so it can be driven from the voltage translator directly, and its output resistance is low enough so it can drive the MOSFET with minimal signal quality loss.

Thanks, makes sense .. IRFZ44N need 10v atleast and my circuit only gives ~6v. But actually started with the same circuit then removed the push-pull transistor pair because with brightness level below 50% the LED was not turning on. The only difference being the R3 resistor was not there in my design, instead there was a 4.7k pull-up at the GPIO2 pin. Does that make a difference ?

And also that I used BC547-BC557 instead of BC547-BC556 pair but that shouldn't make a difference i guess.

@Mr.Stark Does that make a difference ? normally it shouldn't but there must have been something that you've missed. BC547-BC557 instead of BC547-BC556 pair This does not make a difference as the BJTs are used in saturation region (i.e. as a switch).

This was the circuit i used (just posting it for future reference and others who read the thread, sry for paper version instead of computer generated schematic) link.
But this didn't work for me with ESP01 GPIO2 pulled up at 1kHz PWM. Could be a bad transistor possibly, but i double checked the wiring for sure.

@Mr.Stark can't see the image. Says "image not found".

another link https://imgur.com/a/UulbSCM, The resistor at the top between base-collector of NPN is 2.2K

another note is that, 57ohm resistor was swapped with 10ohm one here because the gate resistor get quite warm in this configuration, I had only 10ohm resistor that was beefy enough to dissipate the heat.

@Mr.Stark because the gate resistor get quite warm in this configuration this is an indication of something got/done wrong. We don't expect the gate stopper resistor to heat up in such a configuration.

@Mr.Stark here's a simulation for you. One thing I forgot to include in the waveforms was the average dissipation of the gate stopper resistor. It actually doesn't even reach 5 mW.

Thanks for the simulation, results are looking great. I will definitely give this circuit 1 more try. What software are you using btw, would look to simulate my previous circuit and what happens when i remove the pulldown for example.

@Mr.Stark it's LTspice.

You were absolutely right that something was wrong, I checked all the BJTs i used yesterday and found one NPN with shorted BE junction ... that explains the heating and improper transitions on low pwm side. Now I resoldered with new components and this totem pole circuit works gracefully !!! Thanks again .

@Mr.Stark glad you get it sorted.
